# AndEngine gles2, scala and the sbt android plugin

Tags: android, scala, andengine, sbt

I would like to know if someone achieved to work with andengine gles2 and the android sbt plugin. I have tried everything but the only solution who works is to put the gles1 jar into lib. I have even tried with the Android Library Project that were on the wiki but I can't make it works since there is no maven for andengine gles2.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

- Checkout/download andengine.
- Zip the complete andengine srcs (I called it `andengine.apklib`)
- Reference andengine in sbt like this (replace the path at the end accordingly)

  libraryDependencies += "andengine" % "library" % "2.0.0" artifacts(Artifact("library", "apklib", "apklib")) from "file:/abc/def/andengine.apklib"